# Material Design websites break in firefox

Tags: linux, firefox, browser

I've recently noticed that many material design websites don't get displayed properly on my firefox browser. I've disabled all plugins and removed my `user.js` customization of the `about:config` flags but still, it seems to break the material design icons. As an example, see the image below where the icons are displayed as texts instead:

[image: yellow texts are labels for the desired icons]

The corresponding HTML of the website is this

```
          <span class="material-icons-extended">alternate_email</span>
```

A more ugly example is this
[image: ugly example]

I'm sharing this in the hopes of finding someone that has a similar issue. It doesn't occur on my chromium (hence it's not a blocked resource issue), it doesn't disappear when disabling all plugins and it doesn't disappear when disabling my [users.js](https://github.com/pascalwhoop/dotfiles/blob/master/.mozilla/firefox/4j3t9lg8.default/user.js) file. Short of uninstalling and reinstalling FF on my machine, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: As those appear to be placeholders are you blocking java script execution?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but no, of course I am aware that doing this would have drastic effects. Again, everything BUT the icons works.

Comment: URL of example page?  https://gsuite.google.com/ works for me.... (FF65)

Answer (score 0):

I found the following setting in my settings to have caused the issue

```
// // PREF: Prevent font fingerprinting
// // https://browserleaks.com/fonts
// // https://github.com/pyllyukko/user.js/issues/120
user_pref("browser.display.use_document_fonts",         0);
```

Changing it to `1` fixed it.